# Xpath with sibling not working with button click

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, click, siblings

I am Trying to navigate an html table of appointments. Each row contains a different date, so I need to find the correct row by searching by date, which is td[1] of a 10 column row. The last column, td[10] contains the button to click for more info. So, I need to search by date and then click the button at the end of the table for more info.

I tested the xpath, and it seems to be correct:

```
.//*[@id='id_past_appointments']/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(), 'Sep 28, 2016')]//following-sibling::*[9]/div/a[2]
```

However, when I make it part of a Selenium Python command, with the click at the end, I get the following error: "Element is not clickable at point (925.4500122070312, 11.5). Other element would receive the click: "

Here is my Selenium code:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='id_past_appointments']/tbody /tr/td[contains(text(), 'Sep 28, 2016')]//following-sibling::*[9]/div/a[2]").click()
```

Here is a copy of the html:

```
<tr>
   <td>Wed Sep 28, 2016 9:45a.m.</td>
   <td>Dr. Smiley Schutes</td>
   <td>Medicine followup</td>
   <td>
   <td>Exam 1</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>Balance Due</td>
   <td align="left">2</td>
   <td>
   <td style="text-align: right;">
      <div class="btn-group">
         <a class="btn btn-small btn-link" href="/appointments/37135832">
            <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
               Edit Appointment
         </a>
         <a class="btn btn-small" target="_blank" href="/clinical_note/edit/37135832/lock/">
            <i class="icon-lock"></i>
               View Note
         </a>
      </div>
   </td>
```

Any ideas on how to adjust this so that the click works?
hasc